# latexmk precompiler options

Tags: compiling, latexmk

Are there any precompiler options for `latexmk`  I can use *inside my LaTeX source* files? (For instance, to tell `latexmk` to compile using XeLaTeX instead of PDFLaTeX.) I know how to do that with the `.latexmkrc` file, but it would be more useful to me if I could do it within my source files.

Comment: I think you are searching for [Arara](http://cereda.github.com/arara/)

Comment: I think something like the `arara` parsing should be easy to add to latexmk. Send an email to the `latexmk` developer and suggest it, it is a useful feature.

Comment: @daleif: In my opinion, the current approach, i.e. adapting the relevant rules in a local Latexmk initialization file, is cleaner and, potentially, also more secure.

Comment: True, but anoying for editor users who do not understand the various syntaxes for configuring stuff. in that sense I like Emacs' concept of local variables to be set inside the document and used to configure which engine Emacs should use.

Comment: @daleif: Yes, but there is a reason why Emacs doesn’t let you easily set unsafe file-local variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an improved way of using latexmk from within arara (my thanks to Paulo for helping sort out my initial catastrophic mess).

First, install aRaRa (you'll never look back)

Second, cut-and-paste this into a file in your arara rules directory called `xelatexmk.yaml`:

```
!config
# LaTeXmk with XeTeX rule for arara
# author: Brent Longborough
# last edited by: Brent Longborough
# made to work by: Paulo Cereda
identifier: xelatexmk
name: XeLaTeXmK
command: 'latexmk -e "$pdflatex=q/xelatex @{ action == "" ?  "" : "--interaction=" + action  } @{shell} @{ synctex == "" ? "--synctex=1" : synctex } @{expandoptions} %O %S/" -pdf @{file}.tex'
arguments:
- identifier: action
  flag: '@{value}'
- identifier: shell
  flag: '@{value.toLowerCase() == "yes" || value.toLowerCase() == "true" || value.toLowerCase() == "on" ? "--shell-escape" : "--no-shell-escape" }'
- identifier: synctex
  flag: '@{value.toLowerCase() == "no" || value.toLowerCase() == "false" || value.toLowerCase() == "off" ? "--synctex=0" : "--synctex=1" }'
- identifier: expandoptions
  flag: '@{value}'
```

Then, in your TeX file, one of these, or something else that suits you:

```
% arara: xelatexmk
% arara: xelatexmk: { synctex: no }
```

The addition of an optional style file designator for makeindex is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: What's the advantage of this solution over the predefined `xelatex.yalm`?

Comment: @NVaughan: with the `xelatex` rule, you are running... well, `xelatex` on your `.tex` file. With Brent's rule, you are running `xelatex` via `latexmk` and all the goodies from the latter are automatically available - e.g, no compilation is triggered if the file is updated. Brent is passing the compilation options to `latexmk` via `arara` directives. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Cool! Thanks for `arara`. BTW, why did you choose coding it in java?

Comment: @NVaughan: A cite from arara’s usermanual: “Another feature worth mentioning is the fact that arara is platform independent. I wrote it in Java, so arara runs on top of a Java virtual machine, available on all the major operating systems …”

Comment: @Speravir Thanks. I just was wondering, because Perl and Python are also platform independent...

Comment: @NVaughan: Aah. And then it’s of course a matter of taste … and perhaps of available libraries. Also, think of Windows users: IMHO there are much less users with installed Perl or Python engines then with Java.

Comment: @NVaughan: I know a few languages, but Java is probably the one I use the most in my daily job, so I decided to go with the language I was most comfortable with. `:)` `arara` was written in a few hours, in my spare time. And the available libraries also helped a lot. As a bonus, Java has some advantages (Speravir's comments) and, well, some disadvantages too. `:P` I might try porting the tool to Lua in the future (for a better integration with TeX distros), but it might take a while.

Comment: @PauloCereda, cheers!

Comment: @Speravir, I agree `:}`

Comment: I've been testing the new rules (Brent's) with good results. Thanks both to Brent and to Paulo.

Comment: It's on my list of future improvements for `latexmk` to read meta-comments in the source file to control the engine.  I expect to use those already defined by TeXShop and TeXWorks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think latexmk does any parsing of input files.  It parses the output/log files to determine which files to be looking at, etc, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't actually read the input files themselves, which would mean that this wouldn't work.

An option I haven't explored fully might be to write a small parser script of your own, and specify this as the LaTeX processing program to use.  In your script, read the .tex file, and check for preprocessing directives that you have decided on, then act accordingly in choosing the right compiler, which options, etc.

Comment: My understanding is that Latexmk does no parsing at all; it (mainly) compares MD5 hashes. Moreover, it can make use of the `-recorder` option of `pdftex`.

Comment: You're right about the hashes. I may not have been clear, I was simply meaning it parses the output to determine which files it should be hashing.  It does do a small amount of file reading, but only for a couple of cases, like the `hash_cavlc_ignore_pattern` option

Comment: Yes, that’s right. For instance, Latexmk inspects the log file to find the source files.

Answer (score 0):

As mph and daleif have suggested, I tried `arara`. It looks promising. After installation and setup, one just has to include a series of precompiler commands describing the compilation process. E.g.,

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, article, oneside]{memoir}
. . .
```

Or more complex setups, as e.g.,

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeindex: { style: test.ist }
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
. . .
```

However, `arara` doesn't seem to be quite as “smart” as `latexmk`. For instance, if I  want to clean the auxiliary files, I must do that from "within" the source code---obviously, as it is a precompiler command. But that means that the aux files are trashed after every successful compilation, which is not very useful always. Moreover, one must always declare expressly which aux files to trash---of which, by contrast, `latexmk` has a default set predefined.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: clean: { files: [ helloindex.aux, helloindex.idx, helloindex.ilg, helloindex.ind, helloindex.log ] }
\documentclass{article} 
...
```

As this code sample taken from the user manual shows, you cannot state which aux file extensions to trash (presumably because `arara` doesn't check whether those files belong to the compiled source). So you have to explicitly declare them in the precompiler option.

Perhaps `arara` will become “smarter” in future versions. As for now, it seems to me that `latexmk` is more productive and efficient, especially when you have a local `.latexmkrc` file declaring special compilation parameters.

Comment: Please ask a new question. The rule for cleaning can be improved. However this should be a separate question

Comment: I don't think this is a new question---indeed, it's not a question but an answer to my original question. Cleaning is a feature of both `latexmk` and `arara`.

Comment: I meant the cleaning rule of arara. As I understood you answer correct you are wishing a more intuitive way.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to see whether the functionality of `latexmk` can be obtained using pre-compiler instructions, and I was directed to `arara`. But after checking it out, I found some shortcomings, in comparison to `latexmk`.

Comment: I wish I could take a photo of my notes when I was thinking about `arara` - they are a mess! `:)` In the beginning, I thought of performing checksums, log analysis and other cool stuff in order to ensure the exact number of passes needed to generate a proper PDF from a `.tex` file. But then I gave up, not because it was difficult, but we already have great tools which do a very fine job - e.g, `rubber` and the awesome `latexmk` (I'm a fan of John Collins). I decided to write a general-purpose tool to ease the automation process - `arara` can help with it, but not the compilation itself. (CTD)

Comment: (CTD) The predefined rules are only a small set of possibilites that ship with `arara`. I love the idea of being able to write my own rules, to match my style and needs. And I think that a nice solution would be `arara` used as an interface to `latexmk`. Brent wrote a nice answer towards the concept behind my humble tool. I'm sorry for not providing predefined `latexmk` rules out of the box, but hopefully (with Brent's great help), they will be available in the project repository soon. `:)`

Comment: I've sent Paulo rules for pdflatex, xelatex, and lualatex, all via latexmk, plus another cleaner rule that uses latexmk's -c/-C options